# Magento 2 : Getting Error When Sending ClienteMerksyst filed

Tags: magento2

> "message": "Property "ClienteMerksyst" does not have accessor method
> "getClienteMerksyst" in class
> "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface".", {
> "customer": {
> "email": "customer@example.com",
> "firstname": "John",
> "lastname": "Doe",
> "storeId": 1,
> "websiteId": 1,
> "gender":"1",
> "cliente_merksyst" :"1234567"
> },
> "password": "password" }
>
> rest/V1/customers
>
> - List item

Comment: Can you explain what you are try to do?

Comment: i need to override rest api the Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface using plugin or preference after that overide will magento call the events obsevers email trigger default magento will work or need to create it suggestion and examples

Comment: share the code which you try for this, so you will gethelp into this one.